# Find a number of objects within a specified variable range and assign mean value to each object variable in the range

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of objects having variable X, Y and Z. All doubles.
Now, I want to get a selection of objects within a specific range in relation to eachother, based on X only. And I need to assign the mean X-value for all objects within this range, keeping Y and Z intact for all members.

I sort the list with "simple" .Sort() since X is first..
For example, (just mentioning the X-variable in objects).

1013
1500
2200
2240
2251
2290
3100
3500

Now, I need to check objects inside a range of eachother of say 100 in the list.
In this example would be:
2200
2240
2251
2290

I have tried using index in list as a start

```
if (DPlace2[i + 1].X - DPlace2[i].X < 100)
   {
    DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 1].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
    DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i + 1].X - ((DPlace2[i + 1].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
   }
```

But there could be any amount of objects within this range so the solution is crap.
What is the best solution to do this?

EDIT:
To clarify, here is one example of a List representing my problem.
(My initial problem is a list of objects where value of property X is needed, but this example just shows int to make it easier to read.)

```
List<int> DPlace3 = new List<int>()
{ 
 1175,
 1575,
 2010, //->2015
 2010, //->2015
 2020, //->2015
 3089,
 5050, //->5055
 5060, //->5055
 8100
};
```

Values with comments respresent objects within a *range* of 100 in relation to eachother. Perhaps "range" is a sloppy expression in my question. Sorry! Comment on these rows indictes what I expect the code to change the values to.
This is why I sorted the list and started to try using index of members in list and to check if next value is less than 100 (ie the range) from the previous one. If so, change value of index i to be mean vale of the current and next.
This works pretty well if there are allways 2 objects within the range, but it could be 5. In example above, the firts range involves 3 objects, the second one includes 2 objects.
So, I was thinking there must be a way to code this nice and tidy.
Fairly new to this so I don't know what SlidingWindow is.:)

And it was also sloppy to state "mean value", since it is the mean of only min/max values found in each value range...

EDIT 2:
Found a solution to my problem, but it is "hard-coded" to my specific needs and surely not the most optimized(?)
For me, there can be up to 8 objects within the value-range (as for now).
So, I did my loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DPlace2.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (((i+7) < DPlace2.Count) && DPlace2[i + 7].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 7].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 2].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 3].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 4].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 5].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 6].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 7].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        i = i + 6;
    }
    if (((i + 6) < DPlace2.Count) && DPlace2[i + 6].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 6].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 2].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 3].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 4].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 5].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 6].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        i = i + 5;
    }
    if (((i + 5) < DPlace2.Count) && DPlace2[i + 5].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 5].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 2].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 3].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 4].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 5].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        i = i + 4;
    }
    if (((i + 4) < DPlace2.Count) && DPlace2[i + 4].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 4].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 2].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 3].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 4].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        i = i + 3;
    }
    if (((i + 3) < DPlace2.Count) && DPlace2[i + 3].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 3].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 2].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 3].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    if (((i + 2) < DPlace2.Count) && DPlace2[i + 2].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 2].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        DPlace2[i + 2].X = DPlace2[i].X;
        i++;
    }
    if (DPlace2[i + 1].X - DPlace2[i].X < 150)
    {
        DPlace2[i].X = DPlace2[i].X + ((DPlace2[i + 1].X - DPlace2[i].X) / 2);
        DPlace2[i + 1].X = DPlace2[i].X;
    }
}
```

Since the list is sorted, min-value is allways from object[i] and max value is from the last object meeting the criteria of being inside the range. Average is calculated from these two "extrema" and hence all the loops in my "solution".
Speed is an issue, so I try to stop unnecessary looping by increasing i.
Even if I think I have solved my issue for now, it is not an optimal solution in any way. Tomorrow there might be 9 possible entries and not  8...
Surely, there must be a genereic soluotion to this problem.

Comment: _"What is the best solution to do this?"_ - I am still struggling to see what "this" _is_? Why do you sort exactly? What do mean by "inside a range of eachother"? Would that be a sliding window? Positional? By Value? Please clarify if you can.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that he is asking for sliding window.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens That would be my first guess, too. But it's really unclear to me.

Comment: Question is very unlcear without a better explanation or example data. Since it seems to have something to do with sliding windows, check out MoreLINQ's [`Window()`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/f884919df12b63ebf41de55756dc8ab090a7a00e/MoreLinq/Window.cs#L42) function.

Comment: Try DPlace2.Where(d => (d.X > 100) & (d.X < 200))

Comment: Sorry if question is unclear! @Fildor, I stated in the top section that it is required to iterate all objects in list, all having property X as a double. And range should be based on X, in relation to eachothers X. Hence I sorted the list since I found it to be most suitable to read prev and next. But I want all members inside this range (could be 2-8 or whatever) in the list to end up with the same mean value inside this range, so using index as my (crappy) solution will not work. There might be another range inside the same list too (bigger numbers). Thx U all, will check out sliding Window!

Comment: You are losing me at the "range". What is that supposed to be? Can you show an example, where you do the calculation by hand as you expect it to be made?

Comment: Added a more detailed example. Thanks for your efforts @Fildor
By "range" I mean range of values of objects, not range of objects.

Comment: Ahhhh ... so that's kind of like a smoothing function. Consecutive values within a range of +/- X to the first value shall be set to their overall mean value ... Ok, that makes it fairly clear, I guess. So, I think you are not too far away. But you need to go one significant step in complexity. 1. You need a method to give you the average or mean of the Xs over a slice (from-index, to-index) of the list and you need to extend your iterating algorithm to find those slices.

Comment: Thx @Fildor. There must be a generic solution to this I think. Range is hard-coded at the moment, but will be replaced by a variable at the end (so users can choose what span to use). That is not a problem at all, but to get the whole function generic is over my knowledge.

Comment: I'll see if I have more time later today to come up with something.

Comment: It shows disrespect to those who might help you when the code is indented way to the right rather than properly formatted.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Rep == 11 , I'd assume it's rather being oblivious to it than intentional disrespectful.

Comment: @Fildor Correct. Which is why I'm telling them, rather than responding via something like a downvote.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yep, that's fair, I guess.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Wow, It was not in any way meant to be disrespectful. I just copy/paste code from VS and the indent as in my code will be as is. (My code is probably a mess...) This is my first Q and will make sure not to do it again. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this will be somewhat convoluted, but it seems to work:

So, in this solution, I create a class that performs the transformation.
It operates on the assumption that the input has been sorted by X before as it is in the question.

The algorithm is basically:

- iterate the list of datapoints

  - if it is the first datapoint of a sequence, put it in a roster and continue
  - if roster has elements already:

    - if the datapoint is within +/- 100 of X to the first item in roster
      then add it to the roster and continue
    - otherwise (sequence ends here)

      - Compute the average of all X in roster
      - for each element in the roster add one element to the ouput where X is replaced by the computed average
      - clear the roster
      - add the current datapoint to the roster
- after iteration make sure the remaining elements get written to output
- enumerate output

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = new List<DataPoint>{new DataPoint(1175.0, 1, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(1575.0, 2, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(2010.0, 3, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(2010.0, 4, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(2020.0, 5, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(3089.0, 6, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(5050.0, 7, 1),
                                        new DataPoint(5060.0, 8, 1), 
                                        new DataPoint(8100.0, 9, 1)};
        var smop = new SmoothOperator(100);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{(string.Join(", ", smop.Smooth(input).Select(x => x.ToX())))}]");
    }
}

public record class DataPoint(double X, double Y, double Z)
{
    public string ToX() => $"{X}";
}

public class SmoothOperator
{
    private SmoothOperatorState _state;
    public SmoothOperator(double threshold = 100.0)
    {
        _state = new (threshold);
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<DataPoint> Smooth(IEnumerable<DataPoint> input)
    {
        foreach (var dp in input)
        {
            _state.Process(dp);
        }
        _state.Flush();
        return _state.Outputs;
    }

    private class SmoothOperatorState
    {
        private double _threshold;
        private List<DataPoint> roster = new();
        private List<DataPoint> outputs = new();
        
        public SmoothOperatorState(double threshold) { _threshold = threshold; }
        
        public void Process(DataPoint dp)
        {
            if (roster.Count == 0) // Is this a "first"? 
            {  // Yes => nothing to compare: just add and move on to next
                roster.Add(dp);
                return;
            }
            
            var reference = roster[0].X;
            
            // Is the value within the threshold?
            if ( Math.Abs(dp.X - reference) <= _threshold )
                // Absolute value! Otherwise: 200 - 400 = -200 < 100 is possible ...
            {
                // It is in => add and move on to next
                roster.Add(dp);
                return;
            }
            
            // out of "range => put roster to output
            Flush();
            // and add the current value to the now cleaned out roster.
            roster.Add(dp);
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            // Get the average of the range
            var median = (int)roster.Select(x => x.X).Distinct().Average();
            // fill outputs with the adjusted datapoints
            outputs.AddRange( roster.Select(x => (x.X == median)?x:new DataPoint(median, x.Y, x.Z)).ToList() );
            // clear out roster for next value
            roster.Clear();
        }

        public IEnumerable<DataPoint> Outputs => outputs.ToList();
    }
}
```

In Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HMfK53

With inputs as given in the question:

```
Input: [1175, 1575, 2010, 2010, 2020, 3089, 5050, 5060, 8100]
Output:[1175, 1575, 2015, 2015, 2015, 3089, 5055, 5055, 8100]
```

Comment: Great! I was thinking about creating some sort of temp List, but did not know how to use and how to have the objects in that list "transferred" to a complete List with all other objects as well. Many thanks.